# Returns null when calling method in another class

Tags: java, get, null, return

Very simple question but very little luck.

My problem is that when I attempt to call on get methods `getUserID` and `getPassword` of class `User` in class `Login`, I get null.

I have looked at other posts with a similar problem to mine. Although I found few posts to guide me, a common issue was that the poster had not initialised the class object but I have done that.

I need specific code here because I've tried a lot of things but can't get it to work. I hope that I provided enough info to help you assist me.

## User class

```
public class User 
{
private String userID;
private String password;
private Employee employee;
private String authorityLevel;
/**
 * Constructor for User class - Initialise a fixed password and employee object.
 */
public User()
{  
    employee = new Employee();
    password = "password";
}    

/**
 * Create a user ID and print the user the details of their user account.
 */
public void createUser(Employee employee)
{  
    // Combine staff ID with authority key to make the user ID.
    userID = employee.getID() + "" + employee.getAuthorityLevel();
    
    // Check that there is a staff ID to create the user ID.
    // It also ensures that an employee profile has been created before an attempt
    // to make a user account.
    if(employee.getID() == null){
        System.out.println("There are no Employee details to make a User with.");
        System.out.println("Please enter the Employee details before you make a user");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Your user ID is: "+userID);
        System.out.println("Your user password is: "+password);
    }
}    

/**
 * @return The user ID.
 */
public String getUserID()
{
    return userID;
}

/**
 * @return The password.
 */
public String getPassword()
{
    return password;
}  
}
```

I want to access the userID and password getter methods in the User class to use in the Login class.

## Login class

```
public class Login
{
private User user;  
private boolean accessGranted;
private String userID;
private String password;   
private boolean loggedIn;
private boolean loggedOut;
/**
 * Constructor for the Login class - initialise a user object.
 */
public Login()
{   
    user = new User();
}   

/**
 * Attempt to start a login session.
 */
public void login(String userID,String password)
{   
    // Check that credentials entered are correct for the account the user wishes to log in to.
    if((password == user.getPassword()) && (userID == user.getUserID())){
        accessGranted = true;
        if((accessGranted == true) && (userID.contains("H"))){
            System.out.println("Your login session has started.");
            System.out.println("You are now viewing Yuconz System as HR staff.");
        }
        if((accessGranted == true) && (userID.contains("D"))){
            System.out.println("Your login session has started.");
            System.out.println("You are now viewing Yuconz System as Director staff.");
        }
        if((accessGranted == true) && (userID.contains("E"))){
            System.out.println("Your login session has started.");
            System.out.println("You are now viewing Yuconz System as Employee staff.");
        }
        loggedIn = true;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("ACCESS DENIED BRUTHA!");
    }
}
```

One class creates the user account where the only details are a userID and a password. The other class is where the user can use the details of that account to login. In `Login`'s `login` method I am checking that the ID and password entered match the ID and password of the account that they are trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you never call `public void createUser(Employee employee)` on the instance of User.

SO

`private String userID;` in never initialized...

Try this :

```
public class User{

    private String userID;
    private String password;
    private Employee employee;
    private String authorityLevel;

    public User(Employee employee){  
        this.employee = employee;
        password = "password";
        createUser();
    }    

    private void createUser(){  
        userID = employee.getID() + "" + employee.getAuthorityLevel();

        if(userID == null){
            System.out.println("There are no Employee details to make a User with.");
            System.out.println("Please enter the Employee details before you make a user");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Your user ID is: "+userID);
            System.out.println("Your user password is: "+password);
        }
    }    

    public String getUserID(){
        return userID;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }  
}
```

> Passing the Employee the the User's constructor is the best solution if you need an instance of Employee to creat a User.

If you do not have any instance of `Employee` in your login but just an `id` and a `password` then you can change the User's constructor : :

```
public class User{
    private String userID;
    private String password;
    private String authorityLevel;

    public User(String userID, String password){  
        this.userID = userID;
        this.password = password;       
        checkUser();
    }    

    private void checkUser(){  
        if(userID == null){
            System.out.println("There are no Employee details to make a User with.");
            System.out.println("Please enter the Employee details before you make a user");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Your user ID is: " + userID);
            System.out.println("Your user password is: " + password);
        }
    }    
    //...
}
```

You can instanciate the `User` in the `Login`

```
public class Login

    private User user;

    public Login(){   
    }   

    public void login(String userID,String password){   
        user = new User(userID, password);
        //...
```

}

Comment: This brings me to the other issue I was having before I altered the design. Adding a paramater in the `User` constructor  to take an `Employee` object meant that when I wanted to initialise a `User` object in `Login`, I would get the constructor error: "required: Employee found: no arguments". I do not want to take an object in the `Login` constructor, however, as I would like to implement a login system that takes an ID and a password.

Comment: Ok, then check my updated solution to build the user with its id and password.

Comment: In the edit creating a `User` object allows the user to set their own account details but they can't as the userID is automatically made for them. The edit is set up as if it were the `Login` class which I can't have. The `id` and `password` in my `login` is from the `User` class. Can you please tell me if I am not being clear in my issue? I feel like it is coming across that my issue is with `Employee` and `User` when it is in fact with `User` and `Login`. Thanks

Comment: Made a last update... I don't know if you are clear or not, but I know that now we are far away from your original question... I identified your `null` value and I gave you two solutions to avoid it. So please accept this answer if you agree that it solves your original issue. I sorry but I cannot help you with your whole desgin. SO is not a code factory...

Answer (score 0):

The strings `userID` and `password` belong to the `Employee` object. You're not initialising those values in your `User` class, this is why they are `null`.

You could do it like this

```
public String getUerID() {
    return employee.getUserID();
```

If you want them to belong to the `User` class the way you declared them in the class, you need to change your `User` constructor. e.g.

```
public User(String id, String pwd) {
    this.userID = id;
    this.password = pwd;
}
```

Then you need to figure out if you still want the Employee object or not.

You should reconsider some design decisions

Comment: `userID` belongs to the `User` object. `userID` is created by combining the  `staffID ` and `authorityLevel` of `Employee` class:  
        userID = employee.getID() + "" + employee.getAuthorityLevel();

Comment: I apologise for my formatting. When I press enter to start a new line it just submits my comment.